# Search for strings in ProcessMemory

Tags: c++, windows, string-search, readprocessmemory

So below is some code I pieced together, it should retrieve the processID of the game/application you input. In my case, Minecraft. Is there a way I can now search the memory for strings using something like ReadProcessMemory? Maybe a list of strings and if it matches something it will return something like "Found: (string)"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD pID;

int main()

{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Minecraft 1.7.10");
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        system("cls");
        cerr << "[+] Please open Minecraft 1.7.10 [+]" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
        HANDLE  pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);
        if (!pHandle) cerr << "ERROR" << endl;
        cout << "[+] Found Minecraft with PID: #" << procID << "[+]\n\n"; 
        Sleep(1000);

        if (procID = NULL)
        {
             cerr << "[+] INTERNAL ERROR: Cannot obtain PID [+]" << endl;
            Sleep(2000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly if i think you like to search through the memory of  "Minecraft" for something like "Please enter password"?
If yes, then the answer is not as simple as it seems...

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm aiming for...

Comment: What you can try is to read the whole memory of the process

  while(1)
  {
  ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address,&value,sizeof(string),0);
  cout << value << "\n";
  }

and then apply a search algorithm.
But it may be possible that you read outside the area you are allowedto and then your progrm crashes....

Comment: Can you use Spy++ to confirm that the text is text? It is probably graphics since they would not want you to do what you think you can do. They have experts that can use advanced solutions to prevent hacking.

Answer (score 1):

To find things in memory you use what is called a pattern scanning function.  Internally and externally it's basically the same process but in an external project you use ReadProcessMemory() to make local copies of the target processes's memory regions and then you scan that buffer.

You use VirtualQueryEx to find valid memory regions and then you only scan those regions.

Here is code that can successfully do that:

```cpp
char* ScanInternal(char* pattern, char* mask, char* begin, intptr_t size)
{
    char* match{ nullptr };

    for (char* curr = begin; curr < begin + size; curr += mbi.RegionSize)
    {
        match = ScanBasic(pattern, mask, curr, mbi.RegionSize);

        if (match != nullptr)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

char* ScanEx(char* pattern, char* mask, char* begin, intptr_t size, HANDLE hProc)
{
    char* match{ nullptr };
    SIZE_T bytesRead;
    DWORD oldprotect;
    char* buffer{ nullptr };
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    mbi.RegionSize = 0x1000;//

    VirtualQueryEx(hProc, (LPCVOID)begin, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));

    for (char* curr = begin; curr < begin + size; curr += mbi.RegionSize)
    {
        if (!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, curr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) continue;
        if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS) continue;

        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

        if (VirtualProtectEx(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect))
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);
            VirtualProtectEx(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, oldprotect, &oldprotect);

            char* internalAddr = ScanBasic(pattern, mask, buffer, (intptr_t)bytesRead);

            if (internalAddr != nullptr)
            {
                //calculate from internal to external
                match = curr + (internalAddr - buffer);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] buffer;
    return match;
}
```

Call it like this:

`char* result = ScanEx("pattern", "xxxxxxx", (char*)0, 0xFFFFFFFF, hProc);`

This would scan the entire process's memory for the word pattern and return the first address which contains it.  This is just an example to explain the concept, you will want to narrow your search to a module's address range by finding the base address and size of the module where your string exists.